# Display flex gives inconsistent scrolling behavior on item resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a hovered item in a flex container to increase in size on hover. That much I have working, but the issue is, the window does not scroll consistently.

If you scroll down so that the footer is visible, hovering on the left red box causes the page to scroll where as the right does not.

Ideally, I would like both boxes to behave like the left one.

All suggestions are appreciated

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
  background:green;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
.flex > div {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 1em;
  width:50%;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out
}
.flex div div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;

}

.flex > div:hover{
 height:500px;
  width: 150%;
}
footer{
  background:blue;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:1em;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: what browsers? for me they behave the same

Comment: I'm using chrome 70.0.3538.102. The starting scroll position before you hover is important, you should notice the difference when the red boxes and blue footer are both visible

Comment: yes I tried to reproduce but nothing .. probably not easy to see

Comment: solved with overflow-anchor: none on the flex container